# How do I place my biomes realistically with only a köppen and topographic map?

Tags: science-based, geography, climate, ecology

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to place the biomes in my continent. Though I have researched which biomes can occur in a certain climate, I'm still confused when it comes to the process by which one choses the correct placement of these biomes.

I'm doing a solo wordlbuilding project following the history of a continent in a world that was procedurally generated with SotE's world generator. This generator allowed me to paint a decent enough picture of the world by giving me a topographic map and a köppen map. I also have other data such as wind speed and farming favourability, but it's still rather vague when it comes to biomes.

So my question is: how do I place my biomes "correctly"?

Here are the topographical and köppen map for reference. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[image: Topographical Map]

[image: Köppen]

Comment: There is a series on YouTube for this by Artifexian. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLduA6tsl3gygsjd4WxP_7d8qlzKuBsouo

Comment: Yes, I have seen this series and I already have the climate information. I was wondering if anyone could help me with placing biomes. Thank you very much either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the Koppen map, which gives your precipitation and climate information, as well as the topographical map which gives you your altitude, you may find the [Holdridge System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holdridge_life_zones) elegant and effective to suit your needs with the information you have.

Considering the three axis system uses temperature, humidity, and latitude to indicate likely biome suitability, it's effectively a paint-by-number solutions to your problem here that I think would be believable. You may need to step outside the bounds on occasion, as the system is relatively simple. That being said, often times for this sort of application something that is effective and simple is best.

The most likely tweaks to the detail application of the system will be high-altitude regions, as these will generally be much drier than their latitudinal position might imply. Also, you'll want to watch out for potential [rain shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_shadow) locations on the side of a mountain opposite the prevailing winds. That will alter the area's biome if your Koppen map would indicate high precipitation otherwise. That may be more of an exercise than necessary, as it appear your maps take that into account.

This sounds like a fun undertaking, good luck and enjoy!

Comment: I did not know about this system! It looks very much like what I needed - thank you very much.